# Are there any loopholes in IP restricting sshd?

Tags: networking, security, ip, firewall, sshd

Say that i want to only allow username/password logins on my private network, but restrict all external sources on to key/cert login.
I would do something like this:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no

Match Address 10.0.0.*
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

But is there a way that an attacker would be able to fool this in order to appear inside my local IP range and be allowed username/password logins from the Internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IP Spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing), is a technique where the attacker uses a forged IP source address with the purpose of concealing the identity of the sender or impersonating another computing system.

However, this kind of attack will be nearly "impossible" from the internet because [RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) defines the following blocks that will be used only inside LAN environments:

> The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) has reserved the
> following three blocks of the IP address space for private internets:
>
> ```
>  10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
>  172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
>  192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
> ```

This also means that ISP's on the internet will not route those requests back to the attacker if he somehow forge an ip address from inside your lan.

Since security layers are never enough, and if you have control over the firewall, or if this machine is directly attached to a internet interface, i would suggest you to enable the [Reverse Path Filtering](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.kernel.rpf.html) inside Linux:

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0
```

This will make your kernel automatically discard packages that obviously don't belong to the same subnet of the interface where they are trying to ingress.